# SharePoint - Excel Data Connection Doesn't Allow Automatic Refresh

Tags: excel, refresh

I have exported my SharePoint file to an excel file and have established a data connection. I would like it to refresh every 60 minutes.

I found out how to go into the "Connection Properties" in Excel and change the Refresh Control settings, but the one that I need the most (Refresh every __ minutes) is greyed out.

Is there a way to enable this option?